# What situation can cause Terminating app due to uncaught exception of class 'nil'

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

My app crashed occasionally with

```
2012-10-10 23:19:24.039 [26442:850f] -[NSNull allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff741cbea0
2012-10-10 23:19:24.040 [26442:850f] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception of class 'nil'
```

The object has already been tested `[obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]` before call `allKeys:`

and if I call `[[NSNull null] allKeys]` intentionally, it crashes with

```
2012-10-11 16:22:15.606 [14939:403] -[NSNull allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff73659f00
2012-10-11 16:22:15.622 [14939:403] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff73659f00'
```

I want to know what situation causes `Terminating app due to uncaught exception of class 'nil'` so I can debug this problem.

Answer (score 0):

1: Because NSNull doesn't respond to message [allKeys], so it throws an exception.

2: you should check that your objet can [respondsToSelector:@selector(allKeys)] instead

3: if your NSNull class objet pass the [obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]], then there is a problem in your control statement

Comment: It's strange that it prints "...exception of class 'nil'" instead of "...exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-..." as normal.

Comment: Better is to show us your code. We could better analyze your problem